# Search for duplicate contributions

Tags: civicontribute

We detected recently some duplicate contributions records. How to make a list of all duplicates? We use the field "source" to indicate the year of the contribution. So we are looking of a list of duplicate contributions for instance for source = "2017"

Comment: Could you clarify what's meant by "duplicate"?  Is this an online donation that got recorded twice due to a bug?  Is it someone doing data entry by hand that entered a batch of donations twice?  Donations that were imported twice?  Each one would have a different strategy in my opinion.

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech. All contributions are manually updated by a volunteer, based on bank payments.

Answer (score 1):

We found a solution by using this SQL query:

```
/* === Duplicate contributions === */
/* c contact * b contribution * t temporary */
SELECT b.contact_id ContactID, c.last_name Last name, c.first_name First name,
       b.source Year, b.total_amount Contribution,
       b.receive_date Received,  b.receipt_date Processed
FROM civicrm_contribution b
JOIN (
    select b.contact_id, b.source, count(*)
    from civicrm_contribution b
    group by b.contact_id, b.source
    having count(*) > 1
    )
    t on b.contact_id = t.contact_id and b.source = t.source
INNER JOIN civicrm_contact c ON b.contact_id=c.id
```

Comment: The caveat is that this will only work if your contacts only make one contribution per year.

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech. This is indeed the case, one yearly contribution for yearly membership.